# Setting carret-position in an External Application's text area?

Tags: windows, delphi, window-handles

Thanks to Rob Kennedy's answer to my question on [how to set the Skype Chat window text.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714542/finding-using-the-currently-active-chatbox-in-the-skype-client-thru-the-winapi/5717202#5717202)

However, whenever I set the text using

```
SendMessage(RichEditWnd,WM_SETTEXT,0,Integer(PChar(Edit1.Text)));
```

Then when I click on the Chat Edit control in Skype, the carret is placed at the beginning and some clicking is required to get it "right" again.

Is there a Windows Message for setting the carret position? Or atleast something that I can use to set the Carret Position to the end of the text? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is: [`EM_EXSETSEL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb788007%28VS.85%29.aspx).

`wParam` should be `0`, and `lParam` should be a pointer to a `TCharRange` structure containing the first and last characters in the selection. You want these to be equal (that is, zero characters selected).

For instance,

```
var
  cr: TCharRange;
begin
  cr.cpMin := 2;
  cr.cpMax := 2;
  SendMessage(RichEdit1.Handle, EM_EXSETSEL, 0, integer(@cr));
```

will set the caret just before the third character in the Rich Edit control.