# Creating a function to dig for Windows Handle by Classname(s) Only

Tags: windows, delphi, window-handles

So I just got an answer to my question about [getting the Skype Chatbox handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714542/finding-using-the-currently-active-chatbox-in-the-skype-client-thru-the-winapi/5717202#5717202).

I am now trying to create a simple function, that digs for a handle. Here is how I am hoping to be able to use it:

```
MyHWND := DigForHandle(['Notepad','Edit'],['Untitled - Notepad','']);
```

Params:

1) Array of String: Holds the Class Hierachy.

2) Array of String: Holds the Window Caption Hierachy.

As you see, the 2nd entry in the 2nd parameter is empty, since the `Edit` Class does not have a Window Caption.

Would it be possible to create such function? :)

Comment: You can't use this code as is for finding NotePad as it appears to contain Skype-specific logic (e.g. comparing to "TConversationForm"). Have you tried this with Skype? If so, where does it fail? Does it find the PID? Does it find the top level window?

Comment: @500 - Yeah, I realized that when thinking about it. What I was looking for though, is a way to dig for any handle when I know it's class hierachy, and if there are more than one of the same class, find the right one according to Window Caption. Will test the answer below when I get home

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When I thought about it, I realized that it was actually rather simple - the code I had though, was "confusing" for me, which was why I asked a question here. After trying it out, I found that doing it this way, its a lot easier to read, and not as complicated (IMO).

```
Function DigForHandle(ClassHierachy, TextHierachy : Array of String):HWND;
Var
 Handle : HWND;
 I : Integer;
 PClass,PText : PChar;

Begin

 Result := 0;

 I := 0;
 while (I <= Length(ClassHierachy)-1) do
 begin
   PClass := PChar(ClassHierachy[I]);
   PText  := PChar(TextHierachy[I]);

   if PClass = '' then PClass := Nil;
   if PText = '' then PText := Nil;


   Result := FindWindowEx(Result,0,PClass,PText);

   Inc(I);
 end;



End;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
uses
  Windows, Messages, TlHelp32, SysUtils;

type
  PGetWindowParam = ^TGetWindowParam;
  TGetWindowParam = record
    ProcID: DWORD;
    WindowCaption: string;
    Result: HWND;
  end;

function DigForHandle(const ProcName, Caption: string; const Hierachy: array of string): HWND;
function FindPID(const ExeFileName: string): DWORD;

implementation

function FindPID(const ExeFileName: string): DWORD;
var
  ContinueLoop: BOOL;
  ProcessEntry32: TProcessEntry32;
  SnapshotHandle: THandle;
  TempExeFileName: string;
begin
  Result := 0;
  SnapshotHandle := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
  if SnapshotHandle <> 0 then
  begin
    FillChar(ProcessEntry32, SizeOf(ProcessEntry32), 0);
    ProcessEntry32.dwSize := Sizeof(ProcessEntry32);
    ContinueLoop := Process32First(SnapshotHandle, ProcessEntry32);
    while ContinueLoop do
    begin
      TempExeFileName := ExtractFileName(ProcessEntry32.szExeFile);
      if SameText(TempExeFileName, ExeFileName) then
      begin
        Result := ProcessEntry32.th32ProcessID;
        Break;
      end;

      ContinueLoop := Process32Next(SnapshotHandle, ProcessEntry32);
    end;
    CloseHandle(SnapshotHandle);
  end;
end;

function GetWindow(Wnd: HWND; P: LParam): BOOL; stdcall;
var
  Param: PGetWindowParam;
  ProcID: DWORD;
  WindowTitle: array[0..256] of Char;
begin
  Result := True; // assume it doesn't match; keep searching
  Param := PGetWindowParam(P);

  ProcID := 0;
  GetWindowThreadProcessID(Wnd, @ProcID);
  if ProcID <> Param^.ProcID then
    Exit;

  FillChar(WindowTitle, SizeOf(WindowTitle), 0);
  if SendMessage(Wnd, WM_GETTEXT, SizeOf(WindowTitle) - SizeOf(Char), LPARAM(@WindowTitle[0])) <= 0 then
    Exit;

  if AnsiSameStr(WindowTitle, Param^.WindowCaption) then
  begin
    Param^.Result := Wnd;
    Result := False;
  end;
end;

function DigForHandle(const ProcName, Caption: string; const Hierachy: array of string): HWND;
var
  Param: TGetWindowParam;
  I: Integer;
  ParentWnd: HWND;
begin
  Result := 0;

  FillChar(Param, SizeOf(Param), 0);
  Param.ProcID := FindPID(ProcName);
  if Param.ProcID = 0 then
    Exit;

  Param.Result := 0;
  Param.WindowCaption := Caption;
  EnumWindows(@GetWindow, LPARAM(@Param));
  if Param.Result = 0 then
    Exit;

  I := 0;
  ParentWnd := Param.Result;
  while (ParentWnd <> 0) and (I < Length(Hierachy)) do
  begin
    Param.Result := 0;
    Param.WindowCaption := Hierachy[I];
    EnumChildWindows(ParentWnd, @GetWindow, LPARAM(@Param));
    if Param.Result = 0 then
      Break;
    ParentWnd := Param.Result;
    Inc(I);
  end;

  if I >= Length(Hierachy) then
    Result := Param.Result;
end;
```

Comment: Will test this when I get home. As I dont have complete understanding of how this code works (because I'm a newbie): When I specify the Caption, is it the caption of the final handle it checks for?